# Which Version control?

Tags: version-control, version

If a project has multiple people, say, A,B,C working together and they all edit a same source file.

Couple months later, they realize that what A has been doing is wrong and they want to roll back the file in such a way that only parts/functions/lines/... that A "touched" are removed and the work B and C did is still in the roll back version. In other words, the roll back version has only the work of B and C up to the time they decide to remove A's work.

Is there any version/source control software out there (free/commercial) can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Git and a bit of scripting will do that. Probably a bit of hand work too, but you can resort commits using interactive rebase.

Comment: a bit of scripting? shouldn't `git revert <commit>` be enough?

Comment: Yes, and you need at least one more command to find all commits by someone particular. That's scripting already.

Answer (score 1):

Most VCSs should be able to do this -- it's a reverse merge.  In Subversion you would identify the revisions made by A and merge them in again, but the other way round.  To oversimplify, this means turning line additions into line removals, and vice versa.

```
# Don't want revision 37 because A made it.
$ svn merge -r 37:36 path
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo

Answer (score 0):

I use TFS and Git. But, there are a lot of free and open source version control softwares.  You can find all the source control softwares [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software).

Answer (score 0):

In Git, you would probably do something like

```
git revert `git rev-list --author=A`
```

[Note: completely untested.]

Answer (score 0):

I bet it can (easily) be done with [Monotone](http://www.monotone.ca/) by using `mtn local kill_certs selector certname [certval]' command (see [reference](http://www.monotone.ca/docs/Database.html)) which:

> This command deletes certs with the given name on revisions that match the given selector. If a value is given, it restricts itself to only delete certs that also have that same value. Like kill_revision, it is a very dangerous command; it permanently and irrevocably deletes historical information from your database.

So, by using A's certificate, the above command will eliminate 'wrong work' done by him.